# HttpRequestException when using HttpClient on Dotnet Core on Raspbian

Tags: ssl, .net-core, raspbian

while creating a Telegram Bot which is supposed to run on my Raspberry Pi, I am facing the following error when running code, which is using an underlying `HttpClient`:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SslMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Ssl' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SslInitializer' threw an exception. ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name
   at Interop.SslInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Ssl..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Ssl.SslV2_3Method()
   at Interop.Ssl.SslMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.OpenSsl.AllocateSslContext(SslProtocols protocols, SafeX509Handle certHandle, SafeEvpPKeyHandle certKeyHandle, EncryptionPolicy policy, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteSslContext..ctor(SafeFreeSslCredentials credential, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_0(SslClientAuthenticationOptions arg1, CancellationToken arg2, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.SendWebRequestAsync[T](String method, Dictionary`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The whole program is running on .Net Core 2.2, and perfectly running on Windows.

What I already tried was googling around for some similar problems, and someone proposed running this command:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

as well as doing this:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/dev/null
```

However, none of these fixed anything.

So, what can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33179.

Try the fix mentioned in the issue of setting the environment variable `CLR_OPENSSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.1`.

Comment: Good catch, I searched a while for it.
My error was `Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Ssl' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SslInitializer' threw an exception. ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0B07C065:x509 certificate routines:X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table`. The env. variable fixed it all.